# Slow "Time Ago" PHP function crashes server when calculating long periods

Tags: php

I have a small PHP function which, given a unix timestamp or a datetime, will return a human readable "time ago" or "time to go" string. However when the difference between now and the given timestamp/datetime is extremely long (decades), it will run seemingly forever until the request times out. I'm not a sure why this is happening or how to fix it, so I hope someone might have some insight? Thanks.

```
<?php
function timeago($time) {
if(!is_numeric($time)) $time = strtotime($time);
if($time == 0) return 'never';

$periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
$lengths = array("60", "60", "24", "7", "4.35", "12", "10");
$ending = "to go";

$difference = time() - $time;
if($difference > 0) $ending = "ago";
else $difference = -$difference;

for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++) $difference /= $lengths[$j];

$difference = round($difference);

if($difference > 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
if($difference < 1) return 'just now';

return "$difference $periods[$j] $ending";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not just use [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not check for the **larger** differences first, to fill up the number of years before counting the number of days etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<?php
function timeago($time) {

if(!is_numeric($time)) $time = strtotime($time);
if($time == 0) return 'never';

    $granularity    = 1;
    $dif            = time() - $time;
    $future = $dif < 0 ? true : false;
    $dif = abs($dif);
        $periods = array(
            'year'      => 31536000,
            'month'     => 2630000,
            'week'      => 604800,
            'day'       => 86400,
            'hour'      => 3600,
            'minute'    => 60,
            'second'    => 1
        );
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $periods as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $dif >= $value ) {
                $time = round( $dif / $value );
                $dif %= $value;
                $output .= ( $output ? ' ' : '' ) . $time . ' ';
                $output .= ( ( $time > 1 ) ? $key . 's' : $key );
                $granularity --;
            }
            if ( $granularity == 0 )
            break;
        }
        
if(!$output) return 'just now';
else return $output.($future ? ' to go' : ' ago');

}
?>
```